# Avoiding mutable state to update String

Tags: haskell

I'm attempting to write a function that will continually loop checking if a randomly generated int is less than 5, if it is less than 5 then "e" is appended to a string, once "eee" is generated then exit out of the loop.

This Haskell code prints if a random value between 1 - 10 is less than 5 :

```
useInt :: Int -> Int 
useInt x = x

test :: IO () 
test = do 
   let l = "eee";
   int <- randomRIO (1, 10) :: IO Int
   if(int < 5) then         
       putStrLn "less"
   else
       putStrLn "greater"

test
```

But I'm unsure how to modify a string without introducing mutable state.

To achieve this using pseudo haskell code can use :

```
var mutableString = "" :

useInt :: Int -> Int 
useInt x = x

test :: IO () 
test = do 
   let l = "eee";
   int <- randomRIO (1, 10) :: IO Int
   while(mutableString != "eee"){
   if(mutableString == "eee")
       break out of loop
   else   
       if(int < 5) then 
           mutableString = mutableString + "e" 
           putStrLn "less"
       else
           putStrLn "greater"
   }
test
```

Any pointers to translate above pseudo code to valid Haskell ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use recursion:

```
test :: IO () 
test = let
   loop "eee" = putStrLn "ending"    -- end of the "loop"
   loop l = do                       -- "loop" iteration
      int <- randomRIO (1, 10) :: IO Int
      if int < 5
       then do
         putStrLn "less"
         loop l                -- same value for l
       else do
         putStrLn "greater"
         loop ('e':l)          -- updated value for l
   in loop ""                  -- "loop" start with initial value for l
```

The idea is that `loop l` takes as a parameter the current value of the "mutable" `l`. When we recurse, we pass the new value of `l`. In the `then` branch above we pass the same value since we don't want to modify it. In the `else` branch we prepend an `'e'` character.